# what is the correct punctuation for otherwise!

Tags: punctuation

I am really confused which one is correct? In grammar books "**otherwise**" is a conjunctive adverb and should be at the start of a sentence or after a semicolon, but in dictionaries it comes usually after a comma!

> 1. I think staff should be paid commensurate with skills **;
>    otherwise,** versatile employees can be headhunted by other
>    companies such as international conglomerates.
> 2. I think staff should be paid commensurate with skills​​​ **,
>    otherwise** versatile employees can be headhunted by other companies
>    such as international conglomerates.
> 3. I think staff should be paid commensurate with skills​​​ **.
>    otherwise,** versatile employees can be headhunted by other companies
>    such as international conglomerates.

Comment: _Otherwise_ can be used in various places in a sentence - but there should be no space before a semicolon, comma or full stop!

Comment: @KateBunting I know that putting a space is not correct but I had to because could't bold the punctuations without a space before them!

Comment: OK! I see no reason why _otherwise_ used as a conjunction should not follow a comma, whatever the grammar book says.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure which Grammar book you are referring to but ***"Otherwise" has lots of meanings and can be used as an ordinary adverb, adjective or conjunction** although this seems to be a British use.* And according to Merriam Webster a **Pronoun**

The statement

> "***otherwise" is a conjunctive adverb and should be at the start of a sentence or after a semicolon***,

---

***This is a misconception***

> Like other adverbs, conjunctive adverbs may be *moved around in the sentence or clause* in which they appear.

However according to this source [Ginger Software](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/conjunctions/conjunctive-adverbs/)

> Always *use a period or semicolon before the conjunctive adverb **when separating two independent clauses***. Conjunctive adverbs are not strong enough to join independent clauses without supporting punctuation.

But according to this source [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/conjunctive_adverbs.htm)

> Note that a conjunctive adverb is preceded by a semicolon when it joins two independent clauses but a period (full stop) when it joins two sentences.

Remember

> Use a comma behind conjunctive adverbs when they appear at the beginning of a sentence’s second clause. The only *exception* to this rule is that no comma is necessary *if the adverb is a single syllable*.

Note.

> **Comma Splices** When you want to join two independent clauses, you need a conjunction or a semicolon. A comma alone isn’t strong enough to join them. This kind of mistake is called a comma splice.

---

Following the above guidance notes;

I think staff should be paid commensurate **with skills​​​; otherwise,** versatile employees can be headhunted by other companies such as international conglomerates.

Example

I think; therefore, I am.

---

**However "otherwise" is often used with conditional meanings** similar to our case. I personally think that the use of just a comma is justified when we are joining what then becomes, in my opinion,  an independent and a subordinate clause.

***I think staff should be paid commensurate with skills​​​, otherwise versatile employees can be headhunted by other companies such as international conglomerates.***

Example

> We’d better send it express, otherwise it’ll take days. Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as)

Comment: Yes I realise the two reverences to; "use a period or semicolon" amount to the same thing But I have given both as the phrases used are different.